# Updating the contents of a dialogFragment periodically per firebase data change

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is somewhat complex. Is it possible to change the contents of a dialog fragment when it has the value event listener. I setup the value event listener of firebase in dialog fragment's `onCreateDialog()` method and I want to change the text whenever firebase updates.

Is it possible, and if yes, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

create

```
class ChangeListener(){
  TextView tv;

  public setView(TextView view){
     this.tv = tv;  
  }

  public void onDataChange (String newData){
     if(tv!=null){
   tv.setText(newData);     
}
```

}
  }

```
In Dialog: 

 @Override
 public void onCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceStat){
    cl = new ChangeListener(); 
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           cl.onDataChanged(snapshot.getValue());
       }
    }
```

Then add view to listner onCreatView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);

  cl.seView (tv);
.....
}
```